# Display thumbnails in an object list using Django and django-imagekit

Tags: django, templates, image-manipulation, imagekit, django-imagekit

How do I display thumbnails for my item list....also is it possible to display just a specific  thumbnail or a random thumbnail?  So far I have this in my template:

```
{% for p in item.images.all %}
   {{ p.get_thumbnail.url }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just got an answer to the problem:

```
{% for p in item.images.all|slice:"4" %}
```

Answer (score 1):

To display the image, you'll at least need to use an `<img>` tag:

```
 <img src="{{ p.thumbnail_image.url }}" alt="{{ p.name }}">
```

Comment: BTW...how do can I get four random pictures?